# 'Curve B rises comparatively gently than Curve A does.' - Is this a correct sentence

Tags: academic-writing

This is my first time to be here, and so excited to find here I can rise the questions.
I am learning writing now, and makes me very confused at times.

And is my question, I wonder if this is a correct sentence without any grammar mistakes. Looking forward to someone can help me. A big thank you in advance.
'Curve B rises comparatively gently than Curve A does.'

Comment: 'More gently' would be better

Comment: ...because we don't use _than_ after _comparatively_.  " A is a steep curve, but B rises comparatively gently."

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Take a look at [ask].  You can help get better answers by telling us why you think there might be a problem with this sentence.  For example, you could tell us a similar sentence that you are sure is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> 'Curve B rises comparatively gently than Curve A does.'

No, this isn't a correct comparison.

When you compare something using "than" you either need 'more' or 'less', or use a comparative term. "Gently" is an adverb, not a comparative.

You could say:

> 'Curve B rises comparatively *more* gently than Curve A.'

'Gentler' is an accepted comparative term, and appears in Cambridge Dictionary in examples, so you could also say:

> 'Curve B rise *is gentler compared to* that of Curve A.'

Comment: Thank you Astralbee. I really like this one 'Curve B rises comparatively more gently than Curve A.' , that's what I want to express.